# Retina images using jQuery - Check to see if image exists first

Tags: jquery, exists, retina

I've found some code from several blogs that i've adapted myself a little to display retina images that suit's my current situation with how to display a larger image  for retina devices. The current code just replaces the last letter with the letter 'L'.

The current script works perfectly as all my small images has "S.jpg" and all my large images are "L.jpg".

How do I go about checking to see if the larger one exists, and if it doesn't exist then to revert/ stay with the small version. Currently it tries to show the large no matter if it exists or not.

My html is like so: (I don't want to add any extra tags to the HTML. I.e '-data-retina')

```
<img class="hires" alt="Image Name" src="/images/imageS.jpg" />
```

Heres my current jQuery:

```
if (window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {

        var images = $("img.hires");

        // loop through the images and make them hi-res
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {

            // create new image name
            var imageType = images[i].src.substr(-4);
            var imageName = images[i].src.substr(0, images[i].src.length - 5);
            imageName += "L" + imageType;

            //rename image
            images[i].src = imageName;
        }
```

I know there is some pre-made plugins out there that can do the job, but they either require me to add the large image to the html source of the IMG tag which isn't ideal for me. And I only want it to work with the class name given. Not all.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is to use an AJAX request and see if you get a 404. So, something like the following:

```
  $.ajax({
     url: // large image location,
     error: function(jqHr, aError) {
       if (aError == 'Not Found') {
         // use smaller image
       }
     },
   });
```

I think you could probably add this to a function and then call the function on images of a specific class.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... my large image is dynamic as I have thousands of images with the 'S' and the 'L' could i server this dynamically? I haven't attempted ajax before.

`if ($('img.hires', this).attr('src') != '') {
                    
            }`

Could I not revert back with this line?

Comment: Hm... not sure I'm following you. Basically, you'd have the code that you already have in the question body. Then, after that's complete, you should have two paths - one with an "L" and one with an "S". I think the ajax request will try to get the large image (the one with an "L"), and if it doesn't exist, then it will default to the S image. Unfortunately, it's always going to download one of the two images, and it will always use the L image, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for your help. I've managed to solve this with the following. I'm sure it can be improved as I'm just a beginner with JS. just in-case someone finds this useful.

```
        $("img.hires").error(function () {
            var src = $(this).attr('src');
            $(this).attr('src', src.replace("L", "S"));
        });
```